# Isomorphisms between symmetric, dihedral and cyclic groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

What examples are there of isomorphisms between the groups $S_n,\, D_n, \, \mathbb{Z}_n$?

Thank you.

Comment: $S_3$ is isomorphic to $D_3$, and $S_2$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2$. Quick enough?

Comment: But $S_4$ is not isomorphic to $D_4$ right?

Comment: @MathDamon correct. They're not even the same size.

Answer (score 9):

The only isomorphisms that hold between $S_n, D_n$ is $S_3\cong D_3$ (the symmetry group of an equilateral triangle) but neither of these is cyclic and both are of order $6$, and hence neither can be isomorphic to the cyclic group of order 3: $\mathbb Z_3$.

For $$n \geq 4,\quad |S_n| = n! \neq 2n = |D_n|$$ hence by that observation alone, for $$n \geq 4, \quad S_n\not\cong D_n$$

For $\mathbb Z_n$, since it is cyclic for every $n\in \mathbb Z, n\geq 1$, we have only $S_2\cong \mathbb Z_2$, since $S_2$ is the only permutation group which is necessarily cyclic.

That's it.

Comment: I knew it, you are a closet algebraist! :-) +1